# rsyncコマンドでdest側のオーナー・グループを維持したまま上書きしたい

Tags: linux, ansible, rsync

`rsync` コマンドでファイルをコピーする時、destのユーザを維持したままコピーするようなオプションはあるでしょうか？
現状、パーミッションは維持してくれますが、オーナー・グループはrsyncコマンドの実行ユーザになってしまいます。
`--no-perm`, `--no-owner`, `--no-group` あたりのオプションがそれに該当すると思っていましたが・・

```
[root@server /]# ls -l /tmp/*/*
/tmp/dest_test/dir:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hogeuser hogegrp 0 10月 13 09:49 file
/tmp/src_test/dir:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7 10月 13 10:01 file

*** rsync 実行
[root@server /]# rsync -lrc --no-perms --no-owner --no-group /tmp/src_test/dir /tmp/dest_test
[root@server /]# ls -l /tmp/*/*
/tmp/dest_test/dir:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7 10月 13 10:17 file　　←★hogeuser:hogegrpのままにしたい
/tmp/src_test/dir:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7 10月 13 10:01 file
```

※/tmp/src_test/dir/fileはroot:rootの予定ですが、hogeuser:hogegrpにして実行しても結果は変わりませんでした。

以下、バージョン情報
　rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31

余談ですが、最終的にはAnsibleのsynchronizeモジュール（rsync）を使う予定で、
gitからチェックアウトした大量のファイルを権限周りを変えずにコピーしたいというのが本来の目的です。

Comment: 一応、`-o` と `-g` オプションで owner と group 情報をコピーしますが、owner に関しては root 権限が必要です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--inplace` オプションを使用してみてください。

```
# rsync -rlc --inplace SRC DST
```

参考:
[rsync but keep destination ownership without setting to source ownership - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/1042187/480984)

Comment: 確認できました。ありがとうございます！
ansibleのsynchronizeに--inplaceを設定するにはデフォルトで設定されている--delay-updatesを外すという処理が必要なのも確認できました。